# replace commas with dots and add element to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all commas of a (number) string with dots and add another element at the same time to display the currency

so far I have this

```
$("#myelement").text(function () {
     return $(this).text().replace(/\,/g, '.');
});
```

So far this works and returns for example `1,234,567` as `1.234.567` but how can I add a string/element to it so that I get `1.234.567 Dollars` or `1.234.567 Rupis` etc.

Comment: No need for `$(this).text()`, the callback gets the old text as its second argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `+ " Dollars"` (or Rupees, etc.) to what you're returning from the function:

```
$("#myelement").text(function () {
     return $(this).text().replace(/\,/g, '.') + " Dollars";
});
```

Note that [as georg points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551468/replace-commas-with-dots-and-add-element-to-string/35551484?noredirect=1#comment58791558_35551468), you don't need the `$(this).text()` part, the callback gets the index and the old text as arguments:

```
$("#myelement").text(function(index, text) {
     return text.replace(/\,/g, '.') + " Dollars";
});
```

---

Side note: `,` isn't special in regular expressions, no need to escape it (although doing so is harmless). So just `/,/g`, not `/\,/g`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks alot! :-)